# Out of gas exception though only 99% was consumed

Tags: gas, gas-limit, out-of-gas

We know one of our transactions consumes always **`62_599`** of gas, once we have decided to set the gas limit to **`63_000`** the tx has failed with **out of gas** exception.

[image]

Right after we have increased the gas limit to **`64_000`** and the transaction with the same input was **completed successfully**.

[image]

As I know, the gas consumption in EVM is very deterministic, the same OPs consume always the same amount of gas. So I totally don't understand, why `63000` was not enough for a `62472` transaction. (*code execution is always the same: no extra ifs statements, nothing*)

Comment: Hard to pinpoint the exact reason without code... My best guess is that you might fall into an edge case related to EIP-114 : https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/114, where even if total remaining gas is enough 63/64 of remaining gas is not enough.

Comment: @hroussille Thank you, I think it is now clearer, I assume there are some allocation for a CALL, and it fails, as not enough gas is left. Even though the allocation later is not totally consumed it is still required.

Comment: That's the idea yes. But once again if you don't provide more informations or sample code to reproduce your issue there is no way (at least for me) to say with 100% certainty that this is really the cause of the out of gas exception, that being said, it really looks like it.